# New Google Sites and URL query strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I'm required to build a website using the new google sites. I want to pass url query strings between pages. I'm exploring the class google.script.url a client side script.

How can I get this to work?

```js
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
   console.log(location);
});
```

In my browser console I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What am I missing? How to reference google.script.url?

Thank you

Comment: In order to confirm the method for using the HTML service, can you provide the script of Google Apps Script side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think you are mixing concepts because your tags say  "google-sites-2016" and "google-apps-script", which are different Google services.

For Google sites, as it says [HERE](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/6100429?hl=en), you are not using the right service.

> If you need code editing the new Google Sites is the wrong platform
>   for you and there are many others that will do this for you.

Now, if you want to use Apps Script as you may want for what I understood from your question. Follow these steps:

1) Go to this [link](https://script.google.com)

2) Click  "New Project"

3) Paste this code in the script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getURL() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

4) Go to File -> New -> HTML File

5) Paste this HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
      function onSuccess(url){
       console.log(url);
     }
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getURL();
  </script>
  <body>
    Hello world!
  </body>
</html>
```

6) Go to Publish -> Deploy as web app -> Deploy

7) You will get a link. Go to that link

### Docs

You can find more info about it here:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Client-to-Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Would this method not grab the URL from the apps script page? I'm looking to grab the URL of the google sites page.

Comment: I edited my code for what you may really want. Let me know if it works